# wkhtmltopdf doesn't work in symfony app deployed to heroku

Tags: symfony, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

I have symfony app that generates PDF files.

composer.json

```
"h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.3"
```

config.yaml

```
knp_snappy:
  pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     %kernel.root_dir%/../bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
  temporary_folder: %kernel.cache_dir%/snappy
```

localy my app works and generates PDF files
when I deploy my app to heroku everything works except generating PDF file.

wkhtmltopdf is installed by composer and linked to bin folder
i can run wkhtmltopdf on heroku manualy and generate PDF file, problem is when I try to do the same in my symfony app

I tried setting direct path to vendor folder for wkhtmltopdf binaries but it didn't help

Comment: There is nothing wrong with above configuration.
For some reason problem has been caused by **mb_ereg_replace** function that worked on my local machine but didn't work on heroku.
I changed it to **preg_replace** and all works now